# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 Only & Along Side Windows 10

Tags: partitioning

I have desktop pc and Toshiba laptop.
I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 in Desktop pc and along side windows 10 in laptop.

I have searched for best way of partitiong while installing 18.04 in both the cases but not understood which is good.

Desktop:
EFI 500mb
Swap 8gb
Ext4 /100gb

Laptop:
A
B
C windows
swap 8gb
Ext4 /100gb
NTFS 350gb
NTFS 350gb

Can anyone help me which order is better for increasing system performance like DESKTOP: EFI>SWAP>EXT4 /
ALONG SIDE WINDOWS: A>B>C>NTFS>NTFS>SWAP>EXT4 /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is some what confusing. Let me summarize - you have laptop and a desktop and you want to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop on both of them along side Windows 10.

Now coming back to your original question as 'K7AAY' also mentioned - it's irrelevant in what order your partitions should be? Some of the patitions are even logical also. Or which partition should be bigger than the others?

Some rule of thumb that if you have a Windows laptop with 1 TB of hard-drive/SSD. Keep Windows in 700-750 GB and reminder 250-300 GB for Ubuntu Linux. If you have 16GB or more of RAM you technically doesn't require a SWAP partition also. Within Windows try to keep C drive(Where you install Operating system like Windows and apps/programs) separate than D:(data). So if the C: is around 250 GB then D: drive around 500 GB. 
EFI and other partitions are created by O/S installers so let them do their work.

Comment: Ashu, I have Installed 18.04 LTS Alone in my Desktop. Alongside Windows 10 in my Laptop. Both are working Great. In Desktop my order of partitions are EFI, SWAP & Ext 4 /......In Laptop the Order is A,B Which are Windows default and C for Windows10..Then i have Created Swap and Ext 4 / for linux and then 2 NTFS Partitions to use with Both Windows and Linux. I thank you for your reply above which helped me to understand.

Comment: Glad that it's of some help for you. There is a answer button, please accept the answer then.

Answer (score 1):

The order of partitions would generate a negligible boot  in performance while giving you an excellent chance to corrupt your partitions or get GRUB very confused. It's installed? It works? Good as it gets.